# Agrupar el resultado una consulta por el substring de uno de sus campos

Tags: php

El resultado de una consulta es el siguiente:

```
64000000  Sueldos y Salarios                      13155.00           0  
64200000  Seguridad Social a cargo de la empresa   4471.56           0
```

Mi intención  es obtener a partir del resultado anterior  lo siguiente .

```
64        Gastos del personal                     17626.56           0
```

Al primer resultado se llega mediante,les pongo únicamente el final del proceso,si es necesario les envío todo:

```
$retornos=array();
    $pre_pdf=array();
    for($i=0;$i<count(($completo));$i++){
            $linea=Subcuenta::where('id','=',$completo[$i]['nombre'])->first();
            $subcuenta=$linea->subcuenta;
            $definicion=$linea->definicion;
            $debe=$completo[$i]['debe'];
            $haber=$completo[$i]['haber'];
            $saldo=$debe-$haber;
            $totaldebe+=$debe;
            $totalhaber+=$haber;
            $saldos+=$saldo;
            $pre_pdf['subcuenta']=$subcuenta;
            $pre_pdf['definicion']=$definicion;
            $pre_pdf['debe']=$debe;
            $pre_pdf['haber']=$haber;
            $pre_pdf['saldo']=$saldo;
            array_push($retornos,$pre_pdf);


    }



    $filename=$grupocuentas."___". date("Ymd");
    $pdf=PDF::loadView('/informes/vista_Grupo' 
    ,compact('retornos','grupocuentas','desde','hasta','totaldebe','totalhaber','saldos'));
    return $pdf->download($filename);
}
```

Tengo una tabla llamada subgrupos con los siguiente campos
        subgrupo: 
        definicion:

```
 Espero haberme explicado.
```

Paso toda la consulta.El programa funciona hasta presentar en un pdf las subcuentas con sus saldos, con 8 dígitos,lo que persigo es que al pedir los saldos de un grupo de cuentas , por un periodo determinado y un número de dígitos  agrupar las subcuentas y presentarlas de la siguiente forma .
gastos financieros puede tener varias cuentas por varios conceptos diferentes
tienen en común  dígitos,pretendo que al poner p.ej. 66 o 661  obtener la suma de todas aquellas cuenta que comiencen por los dígitos 66 o 661

```
    $datos=$request->except('_token');
    $grupocuentas="Grupo de cuentas";
    $datos_subcuentas=array();
    $datos_definicion=array();
    $datos_cuentas=array();
    $subcuentas_numero=array();
    $subcuentas=' ';
    $datos_definicion=array();
    $datos_cuentas=array();
    $grupos=array();
    $subcuentas=' ';
    $totaldebe=0;
    $totalhaber=0;
    $saldos=0;
    $sumad=0;
    $sumah=0;
    $longitud=8;
    $desde=$datos['desde'];
    $hasta=$datos['hasta'];
    $idsuscriptor=$datos['idsusc'];
    $subctadesde=$datos['desdesubcuenta'];
    $subctahasta=$datos['hastasubcuenta'];
    $filtrar=$datos['filtrar'];
    $longdesde=strlen($subctadesde);
    $longhasta=strlen($subctahasta);
    //diferencias entre los  dígitos  pedidos  en subcuenta desde
    if($longdesde<$longitud){
        $subcuentadesdefinal=intval((str_pad($subctadesde,$longitud,0))); 
    }
    //diferencias entre los dígitos pedidos  en subcuenta hasta
    if($longhasta<$longitud){
        $subcuentahastafinal=intval((str_pad($subctahasta,$longitud,9))); 
    }

     //las subcuentas que componen el grupo
    $cuentas_id=DB::select( "SELECT  subcuenta As subcta,id AS idsubcuenta FROM subcuentas where "
                                           . "suscriptor_id = $idsuscriptor AND  subcuenta >=$subcuentadesdefinal"
                                           . "  AND  subcuenta<=$subcuentahastafinal"
                                           ."  ORDER BY subcuenta  ASC");
    //array con las id de las subcuentas
    for($i=0;$i<count($cuentas_id);$i++){
        array_push($datos_subcuentas,$cuentas_id[$i]->idsubcuenta);
        $grupos_pedidos=(substr($cuentas_id[$i]->subcta,0,(-8+$filtrar) ));

        array_push($grupos,$grupos_pedidos);
        array_push($subcuentas_numero,$cuentas_id[$i]->subcta);
    }
    //se vuelca en $datos['subcuenta'] y ['definicion']
    $datos['subcuentas']=$datos_subcuentas;
    $subcuentas=implode(",",$datos['subcuentas']);

       $componentes=DB::select("SELECT diarioslineas.subcuentad_id AS nombre, 
                                    SUM(diarioslineas.imported) AS debe
                                    FROM diarios 
                                    LEFT JOIN diarioslineas ON diarioslineas.diario_id = diarios.id
                                    WHERE diarios.fecha BETWEEN '$desde' AND '$hasta'
                                    AND   diarioslineas.subcuentad_id IN ($subcuentas)  
                                    GROUP BY diarioslineas.subcuentad_id
                                    ORDER BY diarios.fecha ASC, diarios.id ASC, diarioslineas.id ASC");
    $componentesh=DB::select("SELECT diarioslineas.subcuentah_id AS nombre, 
                                    SUM(diarioslineas.importeh) AS haber
                                    FROM diarios 
                                    LEFT JOIN diarioslineas ON diarioslineas.diario_id = diarios.id
                                    WHERE diarios.fecha BETWEEN '$desde' AND '$hasta'
                                    AND ( diarioslineas.subcuentah_id IN ($subcuentas)  )
                                    GROUP BY diarioslineas.subcuentah_id
                                    ORDER BY diarios.fecha ASC, diarios.id ASC, diarioslineas.id ASC");

    //convertimos  stdClass resultante en un array
    $comp = json_decode( json_encode( $componentes ), true );
    $comph = json_decode( json_encode( $componentesh ), true );

    //Agrupamos  los datos por subcuenta  
    $completo=array();
    foreach($datos_subcuentas as $subcuenta){
        $a_each=array();
        $a_each['nombre']=$subcuenta;
        $keyd =array_search($subcuenta,array_column($comp,"nombre"));
        if($keyd>0 || $keyd===0){
            $a_each['debe']=$comp[$keyd]['debe'];
        }else{
            $a_each['debe']=0;
        }
        $keyh=array_search($subcuenta,array_column($comph,"nombre"));
        if($keyh>0 || $keyh===0){
            $a_each['haber']=$comph[$keyh]['haber'];
        }else{
            $a_each['haber']=0;
        }
        array_push($completo,$a_each);

    }
    //Analizamos y preparamos los datos para su envío al pdf
    $retornos=array();
    $pre_pdf=array();
    for($i=0;$i<count(($completo));$i++){
            $linea=Subcuenta::where('id','=',$completo[$i]['nombre'])->first();
            $subcuenta=$linea->subcuenta;
            $definicion=$linea->definicion;
            $debe=$completo[$i]['debe'];
            $haber=$completo[$i]['haber'];
            $saldo=$debe-$haber;
            $totaldebe+=$debe;
            $totalhaber+=$haber;
            $saldos+=$saldo;
            $pre_pdf['subcuenta']=$subcuenta;
            $pre_pdf['definicion']=$definicion;
            $pre_pdf['debe']=$debe;
            $pre_pdf['haber']=$haber;
            $pre_pdf['saldo']=$saldo;
            array_push($retornos,$pre_pdf);


    }



    $filename=$grupocuentas."___". date("Ymd");
    $pdf=PDF::loadView('/informes/vista_Grupo' ,compact('retornos','grupocuentas','desde','hasta','totaldebe','totalhaber','saldos'));
    return $pdf->download($filename);
```

Comment: puedes mostrarnos la consulta? quizas puedas hacer directamente la suma en la consulta y con eso ya tendrias el registro que necesitas...

Comment: por cierto, los valores de totaldebe, totalhaber y saldos deberias inicializarlos antes del bucle, no vaya a ser que este metodo que haces sea llamado por otro y al siguiente usuario te añada valores de los anteriores...

Comment: Consulta añadida a la pregunta

Comment: A la atención de Jakala : He añadido la consulta a la pregunta inicial,,No entiendo tu segundo comentario,creo que los valores que comentas  tendrían que estar en ese bucle,soy bastante nuevo en este tema  ¿podrías explicarme como consiguir los sin que estuviesen incluidos en ese bucle?

Comment: No. Lo que digo es que deberías inicializarlos antes del bucle, como haces con $retornos y $pre_pdf.

Comment: A la atención de Jakala. Ok están inicializados al principio de la function(),una cuestión,yo sigo intentando obtener el acumulado de las subcuentas en base a los grupos ,la pregunta  es ¿Está mal diseñada la consulta? ,,porque no doy con la forma de obtenerla